# How to influence realm .distinct results

Tags: android, realm

I have a list of books in my realm database and I am querying the database thus:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<Book> bookCategories = realm.where(Book.class).distinctAsync("category").sort("category");
```

This is working as expected but I have a problem with it. Some of the books in a some categories does not have a book cover.

For example: there's a category named "Thrillers" and the category has 10 books; the above query returns the first item in the category regardless of whether it has a book cover or not. So I wanted it to ignore the first item if it doesn't have a book cover and continue skipping till it finds an item with a book cover. If however it gets to the last item and it still doesn't have a book cover, then it should pick it.

Please is there any way I make this happen?

Note:
Books with covers has `blah-blah.png` as cover values while does that doesn't have covers, the value of covers returns `null` or empty string.

Comment: Where is the `find*` call?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce please I don't  get you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RealmResults<Book> bookCategories = realm.where(Book.class)
                       .isNotNull("coverUrl")
                       .isNotEmpty("coverUrl")
                       .findAllSorted("category")
                       .distinctAsync("category");
```

EDIT: apparently this doesn't work yet due to a limitation in core https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2332

I'll reference this question on that issue.

Comment: Thanks. but it didn't work.It returned the same result for some unknown reason.

Comment: Really? :O did it not sort, or does it not filter or what, I thought it would work....

Comment: It's sorted but not filtered.

Comment: Gah. This is a limitation in core, see https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2332 so depending on the number of items in your db there are tricks to put this execution on a background thread, but it'll eagerly evaluate the set you are looking for

Comment: Good news is that the issue was posted 6 months ago, but the fix was put in progress 2 weeks ago and is now in review, so if it gets merged and released and realm-java updates to that core version, then it'll be available.

Comment: I know it's been 4 months but can you check if this works with Realm-Java 4.0.0-RC1 ?